# How do I get a connection string from a deployed application?

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

I'm writing a Winforms application and I'm currently getting the connection string from the App. The code in the config file is

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="lockitup_Connect" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\C-Sharp\LockItUp\LockItUp.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The line I'm using to access the connection string is:

```
connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lockitup_Connect"].ToString();
```

But because I'm new to C# I think this is hard coded into the program. I'm looking to deploy the program to other users which will obviously change the connection string.

Am I correct in thinking this? If so how can I change it so I can build an accurate connection string each time?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy you should write the appropriate connection string to the `app.config` which is where you are pulling that value  from. The name of the connection string (*`lockitup_Connect` in your example*) is fixed and you retrieve it in the way you have written there. The only change I would make is to write

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lockitup_Connect"].ConnectionString;
```

instead of

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lockitup_Connect"].ToString();
```

As far as how you write to the `app.config` at the time of deployment, that depends on factors like what are you using to package and deploy your application and how do you determine the connection string variables at the time of deployment.